# Tutorials in tag-wikis

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I updated a tag-wiki to include a handful of relevant and high-quality tutorials on the subject. The edit was rejected. Are tag-wikis not an appropriate place for tutorials? May help reduce the amount of basic/simple questions asked by beginners to the language.

Comment: We are probably talking about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7785387 right?

Comment: Yea that's the one.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, tutorials are not something you should include in a tag wiki. Off-site resources to *official* documentation is acceptable, but random links to random sources that have tutorials are hard to maintain and hard to verify if the tutorial actually promotes good practices or useful information. Additionally they can be changed at any time, potentially leaving bad links with bad information.

---

From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user):

> What should I write in the tag wiki?
> ==
>
> See the [guidelines in the blog post announcing tag wikis in their
> current form](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/). To summarize:
>
> - The excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag.
> - Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized.
> - Concentrate on what a tag means to your community.
> - Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag.

Comment: How about an official tutorial? On which side of the argument does that sit? I agree that list of tutorials are not great though.

Comment: I would say, if it's a tutorial on the official website of whatever the tag is talking about, that would likely be alright. I would look for the most general tutorial offered, though. We don't need giant lists of how to do 50 different things, just the one to get them started and get them started from the source.

Comment: What if the official documentation isn't enough to get a novice user started but there are some tutorials that would help. The links I posted were not how tos for more advanced methods but rather basic tutorials to get novices started. Does this not hold value?

Comment: @figurine in those cases, defer to the official documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Adding tutorials to the wiki is:

a) open to abuse by people trying to promote their sites (link farming)

and

b) just another version of [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

So **no**, I don't believe adding tutorials to wikis is valid. Links to good SO wiki answers, yes (maybe), external tutorials, **no**.

Comment: Regarding the first point, surely moderation will be able to sort out any link farming?

Comment: You put in several links, the only way for me to ensure that each of those links was legit would be to click on each one. It's no practical to do this. I juts think it doesn't do what the wiki is designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

On the [page for editing](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/70885) a tag wiki, the right hand bar states that this item is a good fit to be included:

> important links for learning more

That suggests tutorials are fine to be in there.

Comment: Well, arguably that's about (official) documentation, not actually tutorials and such... though I'm not sure.

Comment: The wiki's job isn't there to help the person answer their question. It's to *"introduce the topic"*. The questions answer the question.

Comment: Tutorials serve as a valid introduction to the topic. I'm not talking about tutorials for specific purposes, but more general introductory ones.

Comment: @Deduplicator What better way to 'learn more' than a tutorial? If nothing else, it might prevent people asking some basic questions.

Comment: @Deduplicator Worth pointing out that I don't necessarily subscribe to the view that tutorials are a good fit for a tag wiki, I'm just pasting in SO official text. Perhaps that just indicates the need for a bit clearer guidance.