# Is it appropriate to link a tag wiki to my own site?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I've written a regex-dissector, [Teach Me Regex](http://teachmeregex.com/), a site that focuses more on explaining the regex than on matching ([demo](http://teachmeregex.com/r/guY)).

I know that if you're recommending your product while answering a question, it's proper to explicitly state `"I would recommend that you use PerfectSolution.com, a product that I wrote"`.

If I should ever be explaining a regex and share a link to my site, for instance, I would be doing that.

However, I wanted to add a link to my site on SO's [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex)'s info page ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)) on the sandbox section, and wondered if that was appropriate? I surely could note in the edit summary that I was adding my site, but unlike a post, I wouldn't be notating in the post that it was my site, because the info pages work differently.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I wasn't asking about sponsoring. I was asking if it was acceptable to add my own site to the sandbox section of the info page of the regex tag info page. Already listed there are sites like Debggex and Regex101.

Comment: Hrrm, sorry, too used to spam sites replicating SO.

Comment: The more tutorials the better. And your site looks neither commercial, nor does one *single* link qualify as overt self-promotion. Just don't give it a hyperbolic link text or use pushy formatting. (Oh, and also make it work in Opera!)

Comment: @mario Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291227/tutorials-in-tag-wikis

Comment: I'd wait until you're out of the beta stage...

Comment: I hope the design of your site changes when it's out of beta...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

On the surface, there is absolutely nothing wrong with adding a useful resource to a tag wiki.

However, declaring your own website as a "useful resource" is where this idea starts to become a problem.  What if everyone who had a programming blog decided it was a useful resource for a particular tag.  Even if half of them were really good resources, you start cluttering up the tag wiki with random links.

I'm not going to tell you "don't do it", but I would think twice about it.  My suggestion would be to take it to an appropriate SE chatroom (in your case, [RegEx Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex-regular-expressions) comes to mind).  See what the regulars, particularly some high rep/gold badge holders think of the value of your site.  And if they think there is some value, then go ahead and edit it in (or let one of them edit it in for you).

Comment: As DavidG has mentioned: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291227/tutorials-in-tag-wikis