# Can we delete this off-topic locked "historical" question now that its answers have finished becoming outdated?

Tags: support, historical-lock

Here https://stackoverflow.com/q/11246/1339987

Looks like it dates to 2008...  was last touched around 2012?

Given that Javascript has changed since 2008, I suggest burninating it, since IMO it does more harm than good by now. It's locked so I can't flag or vote.

Comment: I don't see why not. Maybe someone else will chime in.

Comment: Ha. Top two answers are broken links. Time to die.

Comment: w3schools wasn't mentioned enough in the answers

Comment: @Shog9 fwiw, once I dug around, I found that *more* of the links were alive and pointing to maintained resources than I expected. This did surprise me.

Comment: Move 'em to [the wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) if they're not already there.

Comment: "While some of the material might be elementary for you, Jeremy Keith's DOM Scripting is a fantastic Javascript book. Jeremy also wrote Bulletproof Ajax. While I've not read that one, I've heard good things, and I suspect that those good things are correct, given DOM Scripting." +8 votes.

Comment: I don't really like the idea of removing these types of posts in general. However, this removal wouldn't bother me. It is unlikely to help anyone any more than googling the title would in my opinion.

Comment: @Shog9 - It would be nice if the wikis were exposed to google searches somehow.

Comment: They are exposed to Google searches, @TravisJ. They are not, sadly, exposed to *internal* searches.

Comment: @Shog9 - Are you certain? I just googled javascript and found questions/tagged/javascript as the 30th result but did not see tags/javascript/info in the 200 results at which point I stopped looking.

Comment: I didn't say it ranked well, @Travis. Try, "javascript tag wiki"

Comment: You are correct. Hm. That is unfortunate. Is making the tag wikis have more exposure considered a low/no priority?

Comment: The C++ books question is an exceptional example of how such a question should be maintained. It *is*, however, unfortunately an exception.

Comment: If you really think that we need questions like this, Book recommendation SE is at Area 51.

Comment: @TravisJ SE doesn't actually own Google, and so cannot choose how they rank different search terms.

Comment: @Servy - That is a very naive statement to make. Clearly there are tools available to improve search ranking. Maybe if you had more experience creating web applications you would be aware of that.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker mind giving me an answer saying "I deleted it" to accept?

Comment: @TravisJ I've been on SO for almost 5 years and this is the first I've learned that a) tags have their own description pages, and b) that there is tag wiki content covering a *wide* variety of 'off topic' or 'too broad' subjects. Wish I'd know about this earlier, looks very useful - maybe I'm just slow but I think more exposure for tag wikis would be useful. \Pperhaps there could something on this as part of the 'Help Tour' or something.

Comment: @brichins - [I fully agree!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234863/178816)

Comment: Created a [new meta question on whether tag wikis need more exposure](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323800/should-tag-wikis-get-more-exposure). And then came back and saw your link to an existing question on the topic. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sometimes the best way to see what the effect of an action is to take it.

I've deleted it.

It was locked during a time when we locked questions with historical locks (for good reason at the time); but in this particular case since none of the information could be updated, it never was; and so anything resembling usefulness has passed.

If this bothers you, then you should probably also answer the question as to why no one has brought this question up before now.

Comment: It's worth noting that the question was essentially a poor duplicate of information that should have been in the [javascript tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info).

Answer (score 12):

The reason for deleting it should be "Because this very useful information is maintained and kept up to date in the tag description."

In my opinion, SO tag descriptions are a much under-rated feature of the site.  Whenever I come across a new buzzword, the SO tag description is always the first place I go to find out what it REALLY does, as opposed to the official description of a "rich framework" or some other meaningless blather.

SO tag descriptions have helped me find tutorial resources many times.

And in the case of javascript, the tag description includes a list of recommended places to learn javascript, so the question is not needed.

Comment: Tutorials are not a good fit for tag wiki though. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291227/tutorials-in-tag-wikis

Comment: That is an opinion.  I disagree with it.

Comment: And that's the beauty of meta :)

Comment: See also: [Tag wikis need a size and functionality increase](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122197)

Answer (score -11):

shame this was deleted.... ik this might sound weird to the older developers who knew javascript way back, but it would have been interesting (to me) to compare it then and now lol.... oh well

Comment: try web.archive.org?

Comment: interesting, never heard of this site b4

Comment: I think the potential harm outweighs the potential good. While comparing how things are changing might be a useful exercise for experienced developers, new developers could run across this and use outdated resources for developing new code. Since the entire question was geared toward inexperienced developers, the latter outcome seems much more likely.

Comment: Saving for posterity: https://web.archive.org/web/20140902024520/http://yuiblog.com/crockford/